# Modified duration

Tags: finance

A zero coupon bond matures in eight years. It is sold to yield 5% annually. Find the modified duration D(.05,1)

This question comes from the Second Edition Mathematics Interest Theory textbook, section 9.2 #3. The answer provided is D(.05,1)= 7.61905
I am unsure how to approach the problem given that there are no prices or coupon amounts given. Any help in the right direction would be great, thanks!

Comment: You can express it as a function of Price and Face, or make an assumption. many textbooks have an automatic "implied" price and face when they are not specified in the problem.

Comment: @uytt Why don't you do accept the answers?

Comment: I'm sorry I am new to the website, how do I accept the answer? I appreciate your help! @alexjo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Macaulay duration is
$$
D(0.05,\infty)=8
$$
and, observing that $D(i,\infty)=(1+i)D(i,1)$, the modified duration is
$$
D(0.05,1)=\frac{8}{1.05}\approx 7.61905
$$